# Center a div search bar within navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm confused how to center vertically a search bar div area, I've used margin auto and it didn't worked.
[Here's the full code](https://codepen.io/ShiningAss/pen/wNGYvV)

```
.search{
float: right;
width: 200px;
padding: 15px 15px;
margin: auto 0;
background-color: green;
}
```

[Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7TxR.png)
How do I vertical center the search bar div within the navbar?

Comment: It's 2019, use flex. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made with `flexbox`. You should learn [flexbox](https://cssreference.io/flexbox/)

```css
body{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
 background-color: #343D46;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.navbar a{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 15px 15px;
}
.navbar a:hover{
 background-color: green;
}
.dropdown{

}
.search{
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 15px 15px;
 margin: auto 0;
 background-color: green;
}
.search input{
 float: right;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Lorem</a>
      <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
   
  </div>
  <div class="search">
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thanks dude.


yeah Still confused about flebox so still can't use it.

anyway, thanks again :)